# SSMS 2016 missing "Schema" in Filter Settings

Tags: ssms, ssms-2016

I'm missing the "Schema" filter option in SSMS 2016, version 13.0.15700.28, so I can't filter tables, views or stored procedures by "Schema" anymore. This option existed in SSMS 2016 before the recent update that I ran yesterday.[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft this will be fixed in the next release. See https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3058105/ssms-filter-is-missing-schema

Comment: That link now redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect. I scrolled through and didn't find anything on the page related to SSMS.   Just a quick note to save someone else the trouble.